# I would like to use a function written by a Stack Overflow member in an R package. Is there a way to check for permission with the author?

Tags: discussion, support

*[EDIT: I found the user (Rentrop on GitHub), so my specific question is resolved. Was about to delete the question until I realised others may have the same question (including me in the future), so keeping it may prove useful. Alternatively, moderators, feel free to delete it of course!]*

A Stack Overflow member has written an R function which I think will be very useful to others (see [qqnorm and qqline in ggplot2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4357031/qqnorm-and-qqline-in-ggplot2/27191036#27191036)). I would like to include it in my package to make it more accessible to novice R users. Of course, I'd first want to check with the user, ask for permission, and give proper credit. However, I am unable to find contact info for the author (he or she prefers to keep an air of mystery about him or her). Which course of action would be considered appropriate by the Stack Exchange community?

(I don't have enough rep to add a comment to contact the author; plus, would kind of be off-topic.)

1. Respect the user's apparent preference for anonimity, and thereby 'deny' novice R users easy access to the function;
2. Include the function in the package, and include the username, a link to Stack Exchange, and a request to contact you when giving credit in the help page, hoping the user will come across it;
3. Ask what to do in Stack Exchange meta;
4. Other, namely: ...

Thank you for your help :-)

Comment: [Code at Stackoverflow under any license?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/54766/298072)

Comment: You don't have to ask for permission, content at SO is published with a license that allows you to do anything you want with it.  Using it and deriving your own solution from it is *encouraged*.  The only requirement is that when you republish it so that somebody else looks at it and creates his own solution from it that you give attribution.  A link to the original SO post and a link to the author's profile.  Easiest way to do that is to simply add them as comments in source, you can't forget it that way and somebody else might find it helpful, later, to look back at a possibly update.

Comment: Great, thank you both! Awesome policy. "Sharing as default" should itself be commonplace of course, but apparently still rare enough to make my day. Thank you!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The function you want to share is also published here on Stack Overflow, so it is licensed under the CC-BY-SA license that all content on Stack Overflow uses. Specific rules apply for sharing that content. Basically you have to give attribution in a specific way and the license of the shared content must be fitting. See: [Help Licensing](https://stackoverflow.com/help/licensing) and [Attribution required](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/06/attribution-required/).

If you would like different terms, you could negotiate with the original author. Leaving a comment (once you have the reputation required) under the answer containing the function might be okay, but in case the authors wants to keep an air of mystery about them and does not react, I would absolutely respect that.

I see that the author also shared that particular piece of code on GitHub, however did not specify a license there. While this probably means he wants his code to be shared, it's not really clear if he is actually giving permission to do so with the publication of the gist on GitHub.

See also *[Can I use the code in a GitHub project which does not have a license specified?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5521080)*.